# Loading of pages slows down in Selenium

Tags: java, selenium

I have noticed many times that the scraping rate decreases. Initially, when the code is executed I get the rate of around 1 page per second but as I go past 200 pages it becomes more of 1 page per 5 seconds. Any suggestions on what the reason could be?

Comment: When I saw the title, I was going to say this is due to Selenium because it is so slow but when I have read the content, I taught it is because of something else. Could you share more about your project, especially the codes?

Comment: Please share your code to be able to reproduce the issue.